# Job Manager User logging into My Account

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using wp job manager to manage jobs on my Wordpress site and I'm also running WooCommerce to sell products separately from the jobs. I want to create a User for "Jobs Manager" so a member of staff can login to wp-admin and administer jobs and job applications. This works perfectly fine until I activate WooCommerce. Once I do this and the 'Jobs Manager' user logs into wp-admin, it jumps to "My Account" section of WooCommerce on the front end of the site and there's no way for the user to access wp-admin. Is there any way to stop this happening?

I've tried using this method, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

```
<?php
/**
* Redirect users to custom URL based on their role after login
*
* @param string $redirect
* @param object $user
* @return string
*/
function wc_custom_user_redirect( $redirect, $user ) {
// Get the first of all the roles assigned to the user
$role = $user->roles[0];
$dashboard = admin_url();
$myaccount = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) );
if( $role == 'jobs-manager' ) {
//Redirect jobs manager to the dashboard
$redirect = $dashboard;
} else {
//Redirect any other role to the previous visited page or, if not available, to the home
$redirect = wp_get_referer() ? wp_get_referer() : home_url();
}
return $redirect;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_custom_user_redirect', 10, 2 );
```

I'm using the latest versions of wp / wc / and jobs manager plugins

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. If anyone else comes around this sorted the issue:

https://www.role-editor.com/woocommerce-admin-bar-access/